# Resizing layouts for orientation change?

Tags: android, orientation, resize, android-orientation

Normal:

[image]

Landscape:

[image]

See how the ListView overlaps other things on the screen when in landscape mode? How can I keep this from happening?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/main" >

<RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/myWishLists"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp">


<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:prompt="@string/optionsSpinner"
    android:entries="@array/options" />

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/myListsText"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/myWishLists"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:text="My Wish Lists"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />




<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/listsList"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="445dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">



<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lists"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:entries="@array/entries" >

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you can use two different layout for potrait and lanscape

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/main">

    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:prompt="@string/optionsSpinner"
    android:entries="@array/options" 
    />


    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/myListsText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/spinner1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="My Wish Lists"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
    />

    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/lists"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/myListsText"
    android:entries="@array/entries"
    />  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use sub folder for layout & drawable for multiple screen resolution..

see this [Multiple Screen Resolution in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

- You have to use two different layouts for that one for portrait and
  second for landscape and put your landscape layout in layout-land
  folder